# Help with proof of continuous functions with neighborhood value $N$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Prove that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous at $c$ and $f(c) < g(c)$ then there is a neighborhood $N$ of $c$ such that $f(x) < g(x)$.

Comment: The function $h=g-f$ is continuous at c ....

Comment: So do I have to prove that if h=g-f then h is continuous at c then h > 0? How would I bring up the neighborhood N?

Comment: @Ella: One tip is easier than others help you when you write what you have done  with the problem and also accept one answer when one of them is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ 0<\varepsilon < \frac{g(c)-f(c)}{2}$, then there is a $\delta_1>0$ such that $|g(x)-g(c)|<\varepsilon$ and $\delta_2>0$ such that  $|f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon$. Let $\delta = \min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$. Then we claim that $|x-c|< \delta$ has the desired property.

Since $g(x)>g(c)-\varepsilon> (g(c)+f(c))/2$ and $f(x)< f(c)+\varepsilon<(g(c)+f(c))/2$ then we have

$$f(c)-\varepsilon<f(x)<f(c)+\varepsilon<g(c)-\varepsilon<g(x)<g(c)+\varepsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $h(x)=g(x)-f(x)$ and prove that when $h(c)>0$ there exists a neighborhood $N$ of $c$ such that $h(x)>0$ for all $x\in N$. Use the face that $\{ y\in\mathbb R : y > 0\}\subseteq\mathbb R$ is open.

Comment: If h(x) > 0 then there exists a neighborhood N for all x in N? I don't know how to incorporate f(c) and g(c)

Comment: I had a typo in the answer. Also this reads "there exists a neighborhood $N$ of $c$ such that for all $x$ in this neighborhood we have $h(x)>0$", so you are looking for a neighborhood of $c$ on which $h$ is strictly positive. Start with an open neighborhood of $U$ of $h(c)>0$ and think about what continuity tells you about $h^{-1}(U)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $c$ then $g-f$ is continuous at $c$.